# How to avoid site collection larger than 200gb

Tags: site-collection, document

I have a question regarding some sort of document system. Basically I have to set up a simple environment for storing and managing the documents. We are talking about some sort of a small approval workflow, versioning and document publishing etc, nothing special but I would like to hear advise from someone who already set something like that up.

My question is:

We are talking about large amount documents, now Microsoft advises a CDB not more than 200 GB, how should I manage that if there could be more documents in a site collection, I could separate them on different site collection but a SC will be created per department.

Any extra advice regarding this issue will be welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to 'avoid' 200GB content databases, or higher, which SharePoint handles just fine. Feel free to go upwards of 1TB+ for general usage scenarios; 4TB+ reserved for Record Center/>90% read only documents with specific IOPS requirements outlined here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.16).aspx#ContentDB

Comment: I agree to the answer provided by you but the questioner wanted to know a solution for 2013 and not 2016. Can you provide a documentation for 2013?

Comment: > We are in the process of combining the SharePoint Server 2013 and SharePoint Server 2016 content into a single content set. We appreciate your patience while we reorganize things. See the Applies To tag at the top of each article to find out which version of SharePoint an article applies to.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ContentDB

It's identical.

Comment: Can you please confirm how many content databases can we have per Site Collection?

Comment: 1 per Site Collection.

Comment: And what would be the size per content database in the new architecture?

Comment: This is all in the link provided. <~4TB for general use with specific performance/recoverability requirements, 4TB+ for majority read-only cntent.

Comment: So you want to say that basically I could go above 200GB, it does say that it has to meet some requirements to go up to 4TB ... Do you think 1TB of CDB would be fine in the scenario of managing the documents?

Comment: Only when you exceed 1TB are there special requirements in place, which on modern hardware you should be able to easily meet the IOPS requirements. Backup/restore is more of a policy decision. And yes, I've run multiple farms which had >1TB databases for general use without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Last year i was working on a project and that project was for Hospital report system, there they were using SharePoint as a document repository.

There we were maintaining one list in DB where we were storing Current Site Collection name and Content DB name. parallely, we had written one PowerShell script to check current content DB size, if size goes beyond 175GB, powershell script will create one content DB and one site collection and attach this newly DB to this and storing the same info to DB.

I hope this will give a clue.

Comment: But the problem in this solution it will be hard for combining document per department with the correct permissions etc etc ...